# Loading content of Numpy npz file in global namespace

Tags: python, numpy

Numpy allows to export several arrays in a single npz file which can be loaded then, using for instance:

```
infile = "somefile.npz"
inData = np.load( infile)
print( inData.files) #will list all the arrays importable from the file
```

I am interested in function that could load all the data and conserve the naming before exportation in one call.

I can do it `inline' by:

```
infile = "somefile.npz"
inData = np.load( infile)
for varName in inData.files:
    exec(varName + " = inData[\"" + varName + "\"]")
```

which seems to work. But as I would like to make use of this in multiple places, it does not seem to work when moved into a function:

```
def importEverything( infile):
    #imports everything inside the npz input file and keeps the variable in the global namespace
```

It seems that the scope of variables cannot extend from this function's local scope.

It seems that I am misunderstanding something about Python here. Is it possible to do? Is it non advisable?

Comment: Downloading the contents of a dictionary to `globals()` is discouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work by using the `globals` function. In the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) it states that the scope is the defining module not the calling. So the function needs to be defined in the same module it is called from.

```
import numpy as np

def import_npz(npz_file):
    Data = np.load(npz_file)
    for varName in Data:
        globals()[varName] = Data[varName]

import_npz('test.npz')
```

If you want to put your function in a module try this:

```
from import_test import import_npz
import_npz('test.npz', globals())
```

import_test.py

```
import numpy as np
def import_npz(npz_file, namespace):
    Data = np.load(npz_file)
    for varName in Data:
        namespace[varName] = Data[varName]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually not a problem of variable scope. Actually your second code block does not work. If you print out the command you are executing, you get:

```
arr_0 = inData[arr_0]
```

This is why you get the error: `NameError: name 'arr_0' is not defined`, because `arr_0` is not defined, yet you are trying to index `inData` with `arr_0`. What you want to do is actually:

```
arr_0 = inData['arr_0']
```

To solve this problem, just add single quotation marks around the second `varName` so it becomes a string and not a variable name. Try this:

```
infile = "somefile.npz"
inData = np.load( infile)
for varName in inData.files:
    exec(varName + " = inData['" + varName + "']")
```

and everything works. Now you can define your function:

```
def importEverything(infile):
    for varName in inData.files:
        exec(varName + " = inData['" + varName + "']")
```

Input:

```
import numpy as np


x = np.array([1,2,3])
y = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
np.savez('somefile', x, y)

importEverything('somefile.npz')
print(arr_0)
print(arr_1)
```

Output:

```
[1 2 3]
[[1 2]
 [3 4]]
```

Comment: Indeed, I had forgotten the quote marks. Thanks for the input.

Comment: If my answer is correct, please select it to be the correct answer, thanks.